# nginx two server ports two php sites (help)

Tags: php, apache, nginx

i have NGINX running proxies for all my usenet programs that all link to organizr

https://github.com/causefx/Organizr

which works great.

i also have Phlex set up which links your google home to Plex and Sonarr/Radarr

https://github.com/d8ahazard/Phlex

for this to work it needs its own server port. i've been unsuccessful in adding it to my NGINX set up and had to install xampp apache (it runs on port 72).

I would really like not to run both apache and NGINX (i did switch everything to apache yet found it loaded my proxies slower than NGINX).
how can i add another server for port 72 and have it load the PHP correctly?

I have port 80 and 443 linked to mydomain.com and i would like to link port 72 to phlex.mydomain.com

here is my current set up

```
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;



server {
 listen 80;
 server_name _;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }

 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  mydomain.com, 192.168.0.21;




ssl_certificate mydomain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key mydomain.key;

ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_dhparam dhparam.pem;

  location /{
        root   html;
        index  index.php

       auth_basic "closed site";
      auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

      }


       location /plexemail {
       root C:\Plexemail\web;
       }


    location /server {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.35:21;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}

    location /web {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32400;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    location /nzbget {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.21:6789;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }

  location /plexpy {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181/plexpy;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    }  

location /mylar {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    }


    location /htpc {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    }

            location /nzbhydra {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5075;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


   }
    location /sonarr {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8989;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

   }
   location /radarr {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7878;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;


        }
 location /deluge {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7741/;
    proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base "/deluge/";
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

                }
 location /plexrequest{
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3579;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                    }


 location /comics/admin {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2203/comics/admin;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;


                    }
 location /comics {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.21:2202;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    auth_basic "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;


                    }

 location /calendar{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.21:8989/sonarr/feed/calendar/NzbDrone.ics?
  apikey=ec4166d11c2e40baac11df7b483fa956;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }


        location ~ .php$ {
root           html;
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx-1.8.0/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
}

}

 }
```

Comment: Are you able to access your plex server on port 72? Maybe port 72 is already taken. Also you have your plex proxied to 8181. If it's running on 72 then proxy it to 72.

Comment: When I add a new server block to listen for 72 (after shutting apache down) and have the location/ directed to phlex it doesn't loaded correctly. I currently have xampp apache running port 72 linked to phlex which works I would just prefer to run it under nginx

Comment: What port is phlex running on? Because it sounds like what you said is that phlex is running on port 72.

Comment: It doesnt run on a port its like a webpage (check out the link above) Apache is running port 72 and I link it to phlex like a homepage. Yet when I turn apache off and try and get nginx to listen on port 72 and have it direct it to phlex the php page doesn't load correctly

Comment: Well what you posted and what you are describing is not the same. I see in your post that phlex is a server running on port 8181. And you are proxying to that server in nginx. Sounds like you are doing the same with Apache. If phlex was a website then it would be a bunch of text files that you would server from a folder just like any other webpage.

Comment: Looking at the Phlex repo, it's a php page. So you need to look up how to setup php with nginx. Then you'll be able to run that site. There's plenty of instructions on setting up php with nginx online. What will happen is you'll run php as cgi or socket, nginx will pass php file requests to php to interpret, the results will be passed back to ngnix to send to the user.